# multiple preprocessor directives to clBuildProgram

Tags: opencl, preprocessor-directive

According to [the specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clBuildProgram.html), I should be able to pass multiple preprocessor directives using newline as the separating token. I can add one("-D x=2"), but I can't seem to figure out what magical formula will allow me to add multiple.

I've tried passing into the *options* parameter:

```
"-D x=2\ny=2\0";

"-D x=2\n-D y=2\0";

"-D x=2;\ny=2\0";
```

and many other variants of the same to no avail.

I'm sure this is a quick fix or I've misinterpreted the spec?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a regular space as a delimiter:

```
"-Dx=2 -Dy=2"
```

Comment: sorry, just realised i did not accept this - thank you!